# is it faster to first load PK column in query and then get the row Or get the whole row at first query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

as the title says, is it faster to execute a query to fetch PK at first and then with the result(PK), load the whole row?
or it is pointless?

Comment: Quite simply NO. select using a where clause that references the PK

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I mean that in first query we don't have PK. we get PK by first query(with some conditions declared in where clause). and in second query, we use that PK to get the whole row. is it faster in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The way you get your results is by a search on the column, per each row. And it doesn't make a difference on the performance if you have a row with multiple columns and your search is on one column, it returns you the full row (or whatever columns you specify).

So when you search on `primary key` the first time, you get results on a `index`ed column. And the return wont make a difference if it's from one column or multiple columns, so in other words it is pointless to search twice on PK, which is what you do the second time.